# Pass string to edit in terminal and confirm with enter-key in Haskell program

Tags: haskell, terminal, io

Is there a way to "print" a string in terminal and the user can edit this string and press Enter to confirm and pass it back into program?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, using [`haskeline`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/haskeline-0.7.4.3/docs/System-Console-Haskeline.html) (a readline-style library).  It has the function `getInputLineWithInitial` which has the behavior you are asking for.  Example:

```
import System.Console.Haskeline

main = do
  result <- runInputT defaultSettings $ getInputLineWithInitial ""
     ("Pass string to edit in terminal ", "in Haskell program")
  print result
```

Comment: THX for the fast reply. I'll go to try this package